# Multiple different images positioning and alignment in book either as background or/and graphic wrapped in text within or outside the margins

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, positioning, wrapfigure, backgrounds

Hello and thanks for your help!
I need a tool to have as many different images throughout my `book` as I want in every possible position. Here's what I need in details:

1. To be able to add `DIFFERENT BACKGROUND IMAGES` to pages before the Title page (thus unnumbered or numbered in roman/negative), `see MWE`. The text will go over it! Those images would have to correspondingly:

- stretch over the whole page despite the margins! (`on preTITLE1 page`)
- stay within margins (`on preTITLE2 page`)
- be set at any random position of my choice (`on preTITLE3 page`), in other words I can't provide a position like top, bottom and etc. And after that goes my Title page.

2. To be able to add images to different parts of `THE SAME PAGE` and all other pages throughout the document, though for now, I believe mostly or only on outer margin, either:

- completely not touching the text OR
- partly overlapping it (here, if that's not too much work, please share how I can either use `A BACKGROUND IMAGE` to overlap the text or wrap `NOT A BACKGROUND IMAGE` in text the way so it would be partly in text and partly on margin. 
  And I would really love to have some control, if not all possible controls, over those images, like an ability to move them over the page, opacity, rotation and etc. If there's a list of commands, please share. 
  Below I am providing `images` of what I need and `MWE` for the structure of my `book` you can work with. 
  [image: image stretches over the whole page despite the margins!] [image: image stays in margins] [image: image is set at any random position of my choice] [image: images completely not touching the text OR overlapping it]

```
% !TEX TS-program = LuaLaTeX
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,openany]{book}
\pagestyle{plain}
%\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno} 
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{EB Garamond}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage[shortcuts]{extdash}
\usepackage[a5paper,inner=25mm,top=12.5mm,outer=15mm,bottom=20mm,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[all]{nowidow}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage 
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\vspace*{20mm} 
 \vspace{0mm}
\begin{center}
\vspace{10mm}
        {\fontsize{24}{24} {preTITLE1}\par}
        \vspace{15mm} 
        {\normalsize\textcolor{red}{On this page I need a background image on full page with NO margins, stretching outside the frame. Like this}\par} 
\end{center} 
\clearpage

\vspace*{20mm} 
 \vspace{0mm}
\begin{center}
\vspace{10mm}
        {\fontsize{24}{24} {preTITLE2}\par}
        \vspace{15mm}  
        {\normalsize\textcolor{red}{On this page I also need a background image on full page but WITHIN margins. Like this }\par}
\end{center} 
\clearpage
 
 \vspace*{20mm} 
 \vspace{0mm}
\begin{center}
\vspace{10mm}
        {\fontsize{24}{24} {preTITLE3}\par}
        \vspace{15mm} 
        {\normalsize\textcolor{red}{On this page I need a background image only at specific position. Ideally I would need to have an ability to position it myself. In other words I can't provide a position like top, bottom and etc. And I would really love to have some control, if not all possible, over it, like ability to move it over the page, opacity, rotation and etc. Like this}\par} 
\end{center} 
\clearpage
      
\begin{titlepage}
        \centering
        \vspace*{10mm} 
         {\scshape\huge{TITLE}\par}
        \vspace{0mm}

\end{titlepage}
\clearpage


\mainmatter

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\obeylines 


\vspace{10mm}
{\normalsize\textcolor{red}{On this page I'd have images in different parts of the page, though for now I believe, mostly or only on outer margin, either completely not touching the text OR overlapping it. And I would really love to have some control, if not all possible, over it, like ability to move it over the page, opacity, rotation and etc.  Like this}\par}
\vspace{10mm}
\lipsum[1-4]
  \vspace{0mm}
  
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

On this site you are meant to ask only one question at a time. It seems to me that you have asked 7.

As a very partial answer you can use the `picture` environment to position graphics on a page.

```
% picposprob.tex  SE 639125

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{picture}(0,150)
  \put(-40,0){\includegraphics{example-image-a}}
\end{picture}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{picture}(0,250)
  \put(40,0){\includegraphics{example-image}}
\end{picture}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I suggest you read up on the `picture` environment. It will probably take a lot of fiddling on your part to get what you want.

Comment: So you suggest to split my one big question into several small ones :-) I’ll probably do that if no one else answers. I read a lot about pictures, different packages, backgrounds and wrapping but the info is sporadic and incomplete (most likely because I can’t tweak it to my needs being a complete rookie). And even though my question contains several sub-questions, they are all almost about the same topic: how to properly (with better control) add a simple image (not graph or chart) to a simple text page. But thanks ;-)